# Mysql numbers compare in varchar fields

Tags: php, mysql

I need to compare numbers stored in varchar fields, for example i have a table:

```
id | values
1 | 2
2| 154
3 | 88
4 | 35
```

and I need to look for numbers, that are higher than 5, if I could use int attribute for `values` fields everything would be ok, but I have to use varchar. Is there any simple solution?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use

```
CAST(`values` AS UNSIGNED)
```

like that

```
select * from table WHERE CAST(`values` AS UNSIGNED) > 5
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9214b/2)

**EDIT:**

lets say you have signed number with negative sign `-`

then

```
select * from table1 WHERE  CAST(`values` AS SIGNED) > 5
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cff98/1)

Comment: **Unsigned type can be used to permit only nonnegative numbers in a column**

Comment: Nice answer but why do you add extra space in code in every answers?

Comment: @echo_Me - Space before any code start. Yes now it looks fine. Please always do like this :)

Comment: @MindaugasJakubauskas check my edited answer if you have signed numbers with negative signs

Comment: You don't *need* to do that. You *could* do that. You *could* instead add 0 to the column, which (implicitly) does the same thing, with less typing ;-) A better idea might be to store numbers as numbers and strings as strings.

Comment: @Strawberry yes its better but he said that he have numbers as strings-